# Minitest::Assertion: "User.count" didn't change by 1, but by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
test "should create user" do
    assert_difference("User.count", +1) do
      post users_url, params: { user: { email: @user.email, name: @user.name } }
    end
  end
  test "should create another user" do
      assert_difference("User.count", +1) do
        post users_url, params: { user: { email: "ourtusenka@yandex.ru", name: @user.name } }
      end
```

What is the error?
Minitest::Assertion: "User.count" didn't change by 1, but by 0.
Expected: 4
Actual: 3

Answer (score 1):

The test specifies that when doing a POST request to `users_url` with the specified parameters, then the number of users in the database should increase by one.

The error message says:

```
Minitest::Assertion: "User.count" didn't change by 1, but by 0. Expected: 4 Actual: 3
```

The first part (`"User.count" didn't change by 1, but by 0`) means that the number of users in the database didn't change by `1` as expected but kept the same.

The second part (`Expected: 4 Actual: 3`) means that before the POST request there were 3 users in the database and because it was expected to the number increased by 1, the test expected to it to be 4 users after the POST request. But because it did not change, it was still 3.

In short: The test failed because there was no new user created by the POST request. It is not possible to test why there was no user created and the test failed. Because that depends on the implementation in the controller and the model.

I guess it failed because there was a validation failing (for example a missing password or a duplicate email address) and therefore the users wasn't saved.